# Next textbox line

Tags: c#, math, textbox

I have a multi-line textbox of sequences, which the game will play one after the other. For example, the textbox may contain this:

```
RGBY
YGBR
RGBB
```

I understand that to read the first line of a multi-line textbox, I must write this:

**First sequence:**

```
textBox1.Lines[0].Length //Reads first line only for sequence 1
```

But how can I make it read the next line in a general sense? n+1 where n is the previous line.

**New sequence:**

```
textBox1.Lines[0 + 1].Length //Go to next line for future sequences
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: how many times will you ask this question ?

Comment: It's a new question, if you read it Selman22 :-) I've solved my previous questions with `textBox1.Lines[0].Length`

Comment: Soner, does that work? I just wrote it there to illustrate what I want to achieve...

Comment: _"n+1 where n is the previous line."_ So when you tried `textBox1.Lines[n+1]`, what happened? Did you not get the output you wanted?

Comment: are you familiar with the concept of variables?

Comment: @user3403843 I wrote it for asking, why directly not writing `Lines[1]` instead.

Comment: Herm, with math I am familiar with iterative functions. But I'm new to programming, so not so much in that area :(

Comment: Sonar, the problem with Lines[1] is that, it will only be fixed to a finite number of lines. I just want a general code, for all future sequences

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the current index in a variable, a field or property in your class.

```
private int CurrentIndex { get; set; }
```

Now you can iterate all lines, for example in a button-click event handler where you want to  advance to the next line until end:

```
if (CurrentIndex + 1 < textBox1.Lines.Length)
{
    string currentLine = textBox1.Lines[++CurrentIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i < textBox1.Lines.Count(); i++)
{
     var currentLine = textBox1.Lines[i];

     // do what you want with current line
}
```